# Trying to install SDL2-Dev fails with unmet dependencies on Debian

Tags: debian, apt

When executing the following command in Debian,

```
apt-get install libsdl2-dev
```

**I get confronted with an error:**

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsdl2-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I set up the system yesterday and haven't done much to it.
I tried `apt-get -f install` and `apt autoclean`.

This is my entire `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main contrib non-free

# stretch-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main contrib non-free

#stretch-backports
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
```

**EDIT for Stephen:**

```
root@debian:/home/kiryu# apt -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install libsdl2-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 2
Investigating (0) libsdl2-dev:amd64 < none -> 2.0.5+dfsg1-2 @un puN Ib >
Broken libsdl2-dev:amd64 Depends on libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 < none | 13.0.6-1+b2 @un uH >
  Considering libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 1 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
    Reinst Failed early because of libegl1-mesa:amd64
  Considering libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 1 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
Broken libsdl2-dev:amd64 Depends on libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 < none | 13.0.6-1+b2 @un uH >
  Considering libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
    Reinst Failed early because of libdrm2:amd64
    Reinst Failed because of libdrm-dev:amd64
    Reinst Failed because of mesa-common-dev:amd64
  Considering libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
Broken libsdl2-dev:amd64 Depends on libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 < none | 13.0.6-1+b2 @un uH >
  Considering libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 1 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
    Reinst Failed early because of libgles2-mesa:amd64
  Considering libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 1 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
Investigating (0) libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 < none -> 9.0.0-2.1 @un uN Ib >
Broken libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 Depends on libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 < none | 13.0.6-1+b2 @un uH >
  Considering libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 0
  Holding Back libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 rather than change libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64
Broken libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 Depends on libgl-dev:amd64 < none @un H >
  Considering libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 0
  Holding Back libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 rather than change libgl-dev:amd64
  Or group keep for libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64
Investigating (1) libsdl2-dev:amd64 < none -> 2.0.5+dfsg1-2 @un puN Ib >
Broken libsdl2-dev:amd64 Depends on libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 < none | 13.0.6-1+b2 @un uH >
  Considering libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 1 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
  Considering libegl1-mesa-dev:amd64 1 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
Broken libsdl2-dev:amd64 Depends on libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 < none | 13.0.6-1+b2 @un uH >
  Considering libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
  Considering libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 2 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
Broken libsdl2-dev:amd64 Depends on libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 < none | 13.0.6-1+b2 @un uH >
  Considering libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 1 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
  Considering libgles2-mesa-dev:amd64 1 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
Broken libsdl2-dev:amd64 Depends on libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 < none | 9.0.0-2.1 @un uH >
  Considering libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64 0 as a solution to libsdl2-dev:amd64 9999
    Reinst Failed because of libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64
    Reinst Failed because of libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64
Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsdl2-dev : Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgles2-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

EDIT: When entering `apt install -t stretch-backports libsdl2-dev`, I'm getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 udev : Breaks: systemd (< 233-4)
        Breaks: systemd:i386 (< 233-4)
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Edit:

```
root@debian:/home/kiryu# dpkg -l | grep i386
ii  gcc-6-base:i386                       6.3.0-18+deb9u1                             i386         GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)
ii  libbsd0:i386                          0.8.3-1                                     i386         utility functions from BSD systems - shared library
ii  libc6:i386                            2.24-11+deb9u3                              i386         GNU C Library: Shared libraries
ii  libc6-i386                            2.24-11+deb9u3                              amd64        GNU C Library: 32-bit shared libraries for AMD64
ii  libgcc1:i386                          1:6.3.0-18+deb9u1                           i386         GCC support library
ii  libx11-6:i386                         2:1.6.4-3                                   i386         X11 client-side library
ii  libxau6:i386                          1:1.0.8-1                                   i386         X11 authorisation library
ii  libxcb1:i386                          1.12-1                                      i386         X C Binding
ii  libxdmcp6:i386                        1:1.1.2-3                                   i386         X11 Display Manager Control Protocol library
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install libsdl2-dev` (as root)?

Comment: @StephenKitt I attached the requested text.

Comment: Have you by any chance installed `libdrm2` or `libegl1-mesa` from Stretch backports?

Comment: Not that I remember, sadly.

Comment: @GAD3R I attached it!

Comment: Sadly that doesn't solve the initial problem.

Answer (score -1):

It's because of `libgles2-mesa-dev`. If you try to install it with:

```
sudo apt install libgles2-mesa-dev
```

You get:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
libgles2-mesa-dev : Depends: libgles2-mesa (= 13.0.6-1+b2) but 18.1.9-1~bpo9+1 is to be installed
                     Depends: libegl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

And if you try to install the latest mesa, you're breaking 32bit steam, while you are forced to install sid packages for building that mesa.

That mess needs a reportbug about SDL2 for starters, I suggest you do it.